# ImageMagick creates imag with 1px height

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to create label using ImageMagick with the next command from https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/

```
convert 'label:Some test label' label.png
```

The image is

[image]

Adding `-pointsize` does nothing on this issue.  But if I set `-size`, the image is exactly of that size with text that fits to the canvas.

Previously I've used this, but now something goes wrong.  How can I fix it without setting size?

- Ubuntu 21.10
- ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25

EDIT:

Setting `-pointsize`

```
convert -pointsize 108 'label:Some test label' label.png
```

Produces

[image]

Setting `-size`

```
convert -size 100x100 'label:Some test label' label.png
```

[image]

I want to use `-pointsize` but something goes wrong.

EDIT2:

I've found that setting `-font` explicitly works well

```
convert -pointsize 108 -font Liberation-Sans 'label:Some test label' label.png
```

[image]

Comment: If you set just the pointsize, it will make the canvas just big enough. If you set just the canvas size, it will make the pointsize best to fill the canvas. If you set both, it will do both. If you set neither, it will make a mess. TLDR; Set one or the other.

Comment: Some systems do not have a default font. So that is why you need to set the font to make -pointsize work. You can use -font or set a system font. On current versions of IM there is a policy setting for the default font. ` <policy domain="system" name="font" value="/path/to/unicode-font.ttf"/> ` You can set that if you have it.